# Wordpress seo problem

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, seo

I need some seo/mod-rewrite help. I have this .htaccess in my root folder :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^corporate$ shop/corporate/
```

so basically...if I go straight to

```
http://chocowrap.ie/shop/corporate
```

it works but not if I go to

```
http://chocowrap.ie/corporate
```

There is another .htaccess within /shop that is a wordpress install. That .htaccess has

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /shop/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /shop/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

whats wrong? :(

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set your rule as:

```
RewriteRule ^corporate$ shop/index.php
```

Since the shop subfolder is handled by wordpress, the corporate rewrite should be the same (or very similar) to the wordpress rewrite.

Also, it seems odd that you have the exact same rules in your wordpress .htaccess file twice. Though it shouldn't cause any issues, it's redundant.